# Using RestTemplate with Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have client and server sides hooked up with Spring MVC and Hibernate to add, update and search Employees. I am trying to do a database search for Employees but when I do, the page gets refreshed but I don't get the result or an error message in the Console. Here is my code. Any thoughts?

Server side controller:

```
private String key;
private int selected;

public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(int selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }


@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public UserJaxClass searchUser(@RequestBody UserJaxClass jax){

        List<Employees> userList = employeesDao.getList(key, selected);
        List<UserBis> userBisList = new ArrayList();
        for(Employees employee : userList){
            UserBis userBis = new UserBis();
            userBis.setId(employee.getId());
            userBis.setFirstname(employee.getFirstname());
            userBis.setLastname(employee.getLastname());
            userBisList.add(userBis);
        }
        jax = new UserJaxClass();
        jax.setList(userBisList);

        return jax;
    }
```

Server side EmployeesDAOImpl:

```
public List<Employees> getList(String key, int selected) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        String hql = "";
        if(selected==0)
            hql = "from Employees f where f.id like :pass";
        else if(selected == 1)
            hql = "from Employees f where f.first_name like :pass";
        else if(selected == 2)
            hql = "from Employees f where f.last_name like :pass";

        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setString("pass", key + "%");
        List<Employees> employees = query.list();    

        session.close();

        return employees;
    }
```

Client side SearchBean:

```
public List<UserBis> search(String query){
        UserJaxClass userJax = new UserJaxClass();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        userJax = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/BackEnd/search", userJax, UserJaxClass.class);
        userList = userJax.getList();
        userFiltredList = new ArrayList();

        for(UserBis userBis : userList){

            if(userBis.getFirstname().contains(query) || userBis.getLastname().contains(query)){
                userFiltredList.add(userBis);
                    }
        }
        return userFiltredList;
    }
```

Client side search.xhtml:

```
<p:panel header="Empolyee Search" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="10">


                <p:outputLabel for="search" value="Key:" />

                <p:inputText id="search" value="${search.key}" />




                <p:selectOneMenu id="selected" value="#{search.selected}" required="true" label="Select">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="ID" itemValue="0" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="First Name" itemValue="1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Last Name" itemValue="2" />

                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{searchBean.search()}" />



            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
```

Also, here is my UserJaxClass:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserJaxClass implements Serializable{

    @XmlElement
    private List<UserBis> list;

    @XmlElement
    private Employees employee;

    public List<UserBis> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<UserBis> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public Employees getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employees employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }


}
```

Plus, my UserBis class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserBis {
    @XmlElement
    private Integer id;
    @XmlElement
    private String firstname;
    @XmlElement
    private String lastname;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstname + " " + lastname;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to narrow down the problem and then provide more info.

Comment: Empty result set coming back from the database?  Using a debugger to step through your code like @NazaretK. suggests would go a long way here.

Comment: When I debug, it seems like String **key** and int **selected** have **0** and **null** values respectively. I'm not sure why that is the case.